# iText: Word document has multiple columns

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, multiple-columns

I found the following issues with iText PDF conversion: 
- if a Word file has multiple columns, iText produces a PDF with just one column.
- if a Word file has multiple lines of text next to a picture, only the first line of text is displayed next to the picture. The other lines of text are displayed within the picture.

These seem to be bugs in iText. Is there a way to fix these issues or a workaround around them?

Regards,

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Where did you get an iText that converts Word to PDF?

Comment: I used xdocreport. I thought xdocreport uses iText to generate PDFs from Word.